# get_posts() or similar from an array of post ids and display in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a custom search form for searching for a term in the 'postmeta' table and then returning an array of post id's that match that data.

I want to then get the WP post objects for each of the returned post id's in the array and run them through a loop to display the content on a custom page template.

I am able to do this with a PHP foreach loop and echo individual bits of data. Here is the function I have built to test the functionality I talking about.

```
    function sales_search_data() {
      global $wpdb;
       $streets = $wpdb->get_results( 
     "
     SELECT post_id 
     FROM $wpdb->postmeta
     WHERE (meta_key = 'street' OR meta_key = 'suburb' OR meta_key = 'city' OR            meta_key = 'zip')
    AND meta_value = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['street_search']) . "'
    ");

  foreach ( $streets as $street ) {
      echo $street->post_id;
          }
     }
```

The $_POST['street_search'] is user input. And as I mentioned the query is working ok I just can't figure out how to get the Post Object into a loop from an array of Post Id's.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: get_post($street->post_id) ?

Comment: Thank for the help @TomChew-headMillard I have done a lot more reading today and found that if I use:

    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'sale', 'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );

Before a standard loop it will publish only sale posts 2,5, etc. I will just pass the variables from the form to the array and it should be good. Thanks again.